# have left join on 2 columns from first table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a question about MySQL syntax.
I have below 2 tables

```
Name table
ID Routing start end
1  Route 1 RTM1  RTM5
2  Route 2 RTM1  RTM4
3  Route 3 RTM3  RTM2

Location table
ID Code Name  Address
1  RTM1 Test1 Address1
2  RTM2 Test2 Address2
3  RTM3 Test3 Address3
4  RTM4 Test4 Address4
5  RTM5 Test5 Address5
```

This is off course a very simplified version of the databases that i use but this will suit my question.

So i need to output the names from the location tables. How should i do it? How would my left join look like?

```
SELECT Routing, start, end
FROM name 
LEFT JOIN Location ON (not sure what here needs to come)
WHERE ID='1'
```

So how do i distinguish the 2 needed location if i want to output the start and end by name?

Edit:
This is what i expect to have as output:

```
[Routing] => Route 1
[Start] => Test1
[End] => Test5
```

Comment: What is the joining key between the tables ?

Comment: The start and end columns correspond with the code collumn on the location table if that is what you mean

Comment: can you provide sample result what your expecting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  n.ID,
  n.Routing,
  l1.Name AS start_name,
  l2.Name AS end_name
FROM
  Name AS n LEFT JOIN location AS l1 ON n.start=l1.Code
  LEFT JOIN location AS l2 ON n.end=l2.Code
```

(you have to join to the location table TWICE, using two different aliases for example l1 and l2)

Comment: Thanks for your response. ill check it in my database if this realy is what im looking for